# Why can't part of a string be passed onto atoi or stoi?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, substring

I tried doing this to some substrings which were all natural numbers

```
fi = stoi(f[i]) - stoi(s[i]);
se = stoi(s[i]) - stoi(f[i]);
```

where f and s are 2 strings. This was solved when I assigned the part of the string to a new variable. I experienced similar stuff with atoi(str.c_str()). Why does stoi and atoi behave like this?

Comment: What this `stoi(f[i])` suppose to do?

Comment: Turn a substring into an integer

Comment: `f[i] - ‘0’` is the value represented by the digit character `f[i]`.

Comment: Only if the value of `f[i]` is between the characters `'0'`..`'9'`, inclusively, otherwise the result is *indetermine*, depending on the character set being used.

Comment: Note that C++17 introduced [lower-level conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) in `<charconv>` which would let you do what you want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau — that’s what “**digit** character” means.

Comment: There is a problem with your terminology, as there are no substrings in your example code. Perhaps you should, for clearer communication, include example input and desired output? And explain why you think your code should generate that output?

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't part of a string be passed onto atoi or stoi?

It can, to get a substring from `std::string` you need to call [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method. Something like:

```
std::stoi( f.substr( i, 1 ) );
```

assuming you want 1 symbol substring long starting from position `i`. [`std::string::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) does not give you a substring, but a single character from that position, ie `std::string` can act as a container of chars.

Answer (score 1):

If `f` and `s` are `string`s, then `f[i]` and `s[i]` are single `char`s.  `atoi()` and `std::stoi()` do not take single `char`s as input.  They are simply not designed to work that way.

`atoi()` takes a `const char*` as input, and expects it to be a pointer to a null-terminated C-style string.  So, to pass it a single `char`, you will have to construct a `char[2]` array first, eg:

```cpp
char arr[] = { f[i], '\0' };
int i = atoi(arr);
```

`std::stoi()` takes a `std::string` as input.  To pass it a single `char`, you have to construct a 1-char `std::string` first.  However, `std::string` does not have a constructor that accepts *only* a single `char` as input, but there are many different ways that you can produce a 1-char `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
std::string s(1, f[i]);
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

```cpp
std::string s(f, i, 1);
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

```cpp
std::string s(&f[i], 1);
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

```cpp
std::string s(f+i, f+(i+1)); // if f is a char[]/char*
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

```cpp
std::string s(f.begin()+i, f.begin()+(i+1)); // if f is a std::string
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

```cpp
std::string s = f.substr(i, 1); // if f is a std::string
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

```cpp
std::string s = { f[i] };
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

```cpp
std::string s;
s = f[i]; // std::string has an operator=(char) overload
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

```cpp
std::string s;
s.resize(1);;
s[0] = f[i];
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

```cpp
std::string s = std::string_view(&f[i], 1);
int i = std::stoi(s);
```

---

That being said, if all of the `char`s are between `'0'`..`'9'` inclusive, then you don't need to use `atoi()`/`std::stoi()` to convert them to integers.  Just subtract `'0'` from them instead, eg:

```cpp
fi = (f[i] - '0') - (s[i] - '0');
se = (s[i] - '0') - (f[i] - '0');
```

This works because in ASCII, characters `'0'`..`'9'` are defined as sequential values 48..57, thus the above is really just doing this:

`'0' - '0' = 0` -> `48 - 48 = 0`
`'1' - '0' = 1` -> `49 - 48 = 1`
`'2' - '0' = 2` -> `50 - 48 = 2`
and so on...

Comment: `std::stoi()` does not expect null-terminated C-style string.

Comment: @Slava internally, `std::stoi()` just calls `std::strtol()`, which does expect a null-terminated C string. `std:string` is guaranteed to be null-terminated in C++11 and later.